# Can we detect which android application is using the microphone?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Hello everyone i am new to android ndk and want to find two things:

1. Can we detect whether the microphone is on or not?
2. Can we detect which application is using the microphone?

It would be good if anyone knows any idea how to do above through C or through android sdk.

Comment: I would guess not. This would allow you to build malicious programs that listen in to people's phone calls and such.

Comment: I think the person who has asked the ques is talking about its own phone microphone.....he want to which application of my phone is using my phone microphone

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
AudioManager am =  Context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE)
am.isMicrophoneMute()
```

But I don't know how to do it using NDK ([and no one seems to know](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-ndk/-dF5-K5mLrs)).

[AudioManager documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html)

2.

No you can't.
And that is a security decision. As @AndiJay said, malicious programs could then be used.