# Is there any provision in android to know which user application is using which system service

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, microphone, lso

Is there any provision in android or ndk by to know which user application is using which system service?
OR another way by using pid:-

Suppose i have an application which uses microphone, microphone is opened by the system service (named media serv).I can manage to get the pid of above service(media serv).Now i want to know which user application is using the the pid of above service(media serv).

Answer (score 0):

If you are the implementer of the system service -- such as via creating your own fork of the Android OS -- there should be ways to do this via the Binder IPC protocol. SDK apps that implement a service that uses the binding pattern can find out who call them, via calls on their `Binder` object. If an SDK app has the ability to get that information, one imagines that the system service could get the same information from its C/C++ `Binder` equivalent.

If you not the implementer of the system service, then no, communications between apps and system services are private to those processes.

Comment: @CommomsWare sir i am not the implementer actually i try'ed this to know which application of my phone is using my microphone,i also founded another way that is written here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12104284/how-to-know-which-application-is-using-the-microphone can u tell on any of them?

Comment: @chiv: I am not aware of any means for an SDK app to find out if another SDK app is or is not presently using the microphone.

Comment: @CommomsWare sir do u how can we run dumpsys in Android 2.3.3 as i get the permission denial for some permission even after adding permission like android.permission.DUMP