# dumpsys not running in 2.3

Tags: android, android-ndk, media-player, dump

i ran the following instruction `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/dumpsys media.player")//INSTRUCTION TO DUMP MEDIA PLAYER INFO;` in android 2.3.3 but i am getting permission denial.
My manifest is like this i have given all the permissions,this works well in 2.2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.SampleDumpsys.Activity"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES" />//ALL PERMISSIONS
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCOUNT_MANAGER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_APPWIDGET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BRICK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_CACHE_FILES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DIAGNOSTIC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DUMP" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FACTORY_TEST" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FORCE_BACK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_PACKAGE_SIZE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.HARDWARE_TEST" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_LOCATION_PROVIDER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNAL_SYSTEM_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_APP_TOKENS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MASTER_CLEAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_FORMAT_FILESYSTEMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_FRAME_BUFFER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INPUT_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ACTIVITY_WATCHER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALWAYS_FINISH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ANIMATION_SCALE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ORIENTATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_POINTER_SPEED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_PROCESS_LIMIT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SIGNAL_PERSISTENT_PROCESSES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STATUS_BAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SUBSCRIBED_FEEDS_READ" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SUBSCRIBED_FEEDS_WRITE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name=".SampleDumpsysActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>`
```

What should i do now?I can't add the root permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the permissions that you requested you cannot hold, unless you are signed by the same signing key that signed the firmware. Some you might be able to hold if you are installed as part of the firmware, even though you are signed by a different key.

`dumpsys` is designed to be run by a developer, from a development machine, via `adb shell`. It is not designed to be run by an app on a device. My understanding is that you would need the `DUMP` permission, which can only be held if you are either signed by the firmware's signing key or are installed on the firmware's partition. Normal SDK apps are neither.

Comment: thanks for the reply sir....is there anything that i can done at application level to run the dumpsys command as i need it to run for my project

Comment: @chiv: "is there anything that i can done at application level to run the dumpsys command" -- no, only via a ROM mod or rooting your device.

Comment: @CommomnsWare: Sir then can u suggest anyway how to find out which application(name) is using microphone....

Comment: @chiv: As [I commented previously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109401/is-there-any-provision-in-android-to-know-which-user-application-is-using-which#comment16187387_12109563), I am not aware of any means for an SDK app to find out if another SDK app is or is not presently using the microphone.

Comment: @CommomnsWare:ok sir....can u give any info where can i get help related to this?